# Query Output for NVLs

Tags: sql, oracle

Query -

```sql
select A,B 
from ABC 
where B like '%AMBAUS61%'
;
```

Output -

```
col A   col B
BIC     AMBAUS61
BIC     AMBAUS61AABC
BIC     AMBAUS61XXXX
BIC     AMBAUS61XXYZ
```

Col B contains values 8 or 12, so i want to output the query like -

Query -

```
select A,B 
from ABC 
where B like '%AMBAUS61%'
and A = 'BIC'
and B like NVL('%ABC%','%AMBAUS61%');
```

Output-

```
col A   Col B 
BIC     AMBAUS61AABC
```

It's working fine I am inserting right value but there may be a scenario where I want to check only 8 digit.

Like-

```sql
select A,B 
from ABC 
where B like '%AMBAUS61%'
and A = 'BIC'
and B like NVL('%ABCD%','%AMBAUS61%');
```

```
Col A  col B
null   null
```

Here query output is coming blank where I want the output like  below -

```
col A   col B
BIC     AMBAUS61
```

I am calling this using java connections. Please any one suggest me, how can I get the below output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're wrongly using `NVL` function. This:

```
NVL('%ABCD%','%AMBAUS61%')
```

says: "If `'%ABCD%'` is `NULL`, then take `'%AMBAUS61%'`" which is never true. Perhaps you meant to use

```
and (   B like '%ABCD%'
     or B like '%AMBAUS61%'
    )
and B is not null --> optionally; I don't know whether you want it or not
```